# Symfony4 DATABASE_URL in .env not working

Tags: symfony4

I'm trying to use Symfony 4 with MySQL on Windows Server and IIS.
The setting in .env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony
```

just not working, I tried `php artisan config:cache` successfully and restarted IIS as well, but still not luck.
Is there any thing else I can do? thanks!

Comment: "php artisan" is a Laravel thing.  "php bin/console cache:clear" is a Symfony thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after running the

```
php artisan config:cache
```

You still need to use the

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

After all this, restart your iis server. I tried this before, it should work.

Comment: This entire thing is completely confusing.  Title says Symfony.  artisan is a Laravel console tool.  So which is it?